# Data Driven testing with Protractor

Tags: javascript, excel, protractor

I have been working with Protractor for a couple of weeks now and have been impressed . The one thing I am getting stuck on is how would you go about doing data driven testing in Protractor when the data comes for and excel spreadsheet.

For example say you have a spreadsheet call users.xls

user.xls has two Columns and 4 rows Like this.

```
|UesrId| Password|
|user1 | pass1   |
|user2 | pass2   |
|user3 | pass3   |
```

How can I read that excel spread sheet then loop thru my data passing the value from user.xls to my test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow! no one answered this question for 6 months?

You need to use csvtojson plugin to convert csv file to json and get the protractor test to read from the json file. It is better to integrate it with gulp so gulp will regenerate the json file for any changes made to the csv file

Sample code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var convert = require('gulp-convert');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('convertCsv', function() {
    console.log('converting');
    gulp.src('./TestData/*.csv')
        .pipe(convert({from: 'csv', to:'json'}))
        .pipe(rename({extname: '.json'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./TestData/json/'));
});

gulp.task('csv', function () {
    console.log('watching');
    gulp.watch('./TestData/*.csv', ['convertCsv']);
});
```

To use the data:

```
describe('LoginPage.', function() {
    var loginPage = require('../PageObjects/LoginPage.js');
    var loginData = require('../TestData/json/loginData.json');

    loginData.forEach(function (data) {
        it(data.description, function () {
            loginPage.usernameField.sendKeys(data.username);
            loginPage.passwordField.sendKeys(data.password);
            loginPage.loginButton.click();                
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In the above code where are you using 'csvtojson' plugin?